# How to get a part of an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer as a new UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: swift

I'm playing around with image manipulation in swift.

Using [this](https://github.com/mhorga/ImageProcessing/blob/master/demo.playground/Sources/RGBA.swift) code to access image pixels.

The image pixels are pointed at with an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.

All pixels are in one list of data and every pixel location needs to be calculated with:

```
let index = y * rgba.width + x
let pixel = pixels[index]
```

I'm trying to add a `subscript` so for the get

```
public subscript(index: Int) -> [Pixel] {
    get {
        var column = [Pixel]()
        for i in 0..<height {
            column.append(pixels[index*height + i])
        }

        return column
    }
}
```

So is there a way of returning an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` pointing to right column? instead of an array?

I'm trying to avoid more memory allocation.

Thanks

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the pixel data is arranged in *rows,* not columns. In other words, the pixels for a column  are not in contiguous memory.

Comment: Also note that UnsafeMutableBufferPointer is "non-owning" and would only be valid as long as the underlying elements storage exists.

Comment: That RGBA code leaks memory: the allocated memory for the pixel data is never released.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR the code is from this blog:

http://mhorga.org/2015/10/19/image-processing-in-ios-part-3.html

Comment: My mistake about the rows/cloumns

Comment: @MartinR can you explain a bit more about the release of memory and "non-owning"

Comment: An unsafe (buffer) pointer is just a pointer into a memory location. It does not "own" the memory, i.e. it is no "strong reference" which keeps that memory alive. The buffer pointer does not notice if the underlying memory is deallocated.

Comment: @MartinR, Do you have any suggestions how to implement this the right way?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like that?:

```
public subscript(rowIndex: Int) -> UnsafePointer<Pixel> {
  return pixels.baseAddress!.advanced(by: rowIndex * height)
}
public subscript(rowIndex: Int) -> UnsafeBufferPointer<Pixel> {
  return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self[rowIndex], count: height)
}
```

Comment: It just shows you how to do it, you need to integrate that in your specific setup.